# Dealing with phone's back button: Back button on home activity always to cause app exit

Tags: android, button, android-activity, behavior, back

Let's say I have 4 activities in my app:
A (main activity)
B
C
D

I would like that pressing back in Activity A always produce application exit.
In my case if activity flow goes like this A > B > C > A, then if I push back button, I will go to activity C. I want, at that moment, my app to exit.

I assume, app should somehow delete activity history when main activity is active.
How is this to be done?

Thanks

Comment: What is your preferred behaviour if you go to A > B > C and then press back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch your home activity do so with the clear top flag set. This causes the back stack to be cleared.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks. Setting launch mode in manifest to singleTop worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the above behaviour then use the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) to launch A. This will clear the all the activities above A