# onDestroy is not called after pressing the back button

Tags: android

I have an activity1(inside a tabhost) that will call another activity(activity2) when an event happens. And the activity2 will call another activity(activity3) when other event happen. Then the activity2 and 3 will finish() themselves and go back to activity1.
My problem is, if I am on activity1, and press the back button, activitiy1 will get destory() properly, which make sense. But when I trigger events and go to activity2 or activity3, then finish the event and go back to activity1, then when I press back button, the activity1 didn't get destory() properly, so next time when i enter my app again, it will crash.

Here is my codes:

activity1:

```
public void onClick(View v)
            {
Intent feedbackintent = new Intent(StartActivity.this,   //activity1 calling activity2
                        FeedBackActivity.class);

                    startActivity(feedbackintent);
```

activity2:

```
public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(FeedBackActivity.this, //act2 called act3, and finish act2 itself
                        SaveNewRecord.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                finish();
            }
```

activity3:

```
savesomething...()  //act3 do something and finish itself and go back to act1
finish();
```

Comment: what error u get on app crash?

Comment: When I press the back button(after act2,3 destoryed), I got E:
Fatal signal 11(SIGSEGV) at 0x0000..

And when I press my app again, it is black screen for 2 seconds, then nothing pops out, there is no error message

Comment: Have you overridden the back button, either with onBackPressed() or onKeyDown()?

Comment: NO.
BUt i notice a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046234/dealing-with-phones-back-button-back-button-on-home-activity-always-to-cause-a

Comment: Try to use flag to clear the top activity from the stack using addFlag Method in intent. mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: Um, could you explain little bit more? which intent? which activity?

Comment: BTW, My activity 1->2(finish)->3(finish)->1  so there is no intent I could set

Comment: Whenever you are moving from Activity A to B, Activity A goes in Stack,Now you moves from B to C,again Activity B goes in stack, Now at the top of stack we have Activity C. Everytime you call Intent, its important to clear the stack, so that only Single activity Exists in it

Comment: Doesnt work, I tried it.
Maybe the problem is activity1 is inside a tabactivity?

Comment: Would you post every LogCat statement within one second of the time stamp associate with the `FATAL SIGNAL 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)`? (In other words, if `FATAL...` happened at 12:23:34.456, post every command from 12:23:34.000 through 12:23:35.000.) Some elements need to be explicitly released, otherwise you will see this error.